# How to sort and filter in reactjs redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a list of  items in an array which is coming from backend. I am using redux for state management in my app. Here I have a dropdown and a text field to search. When user select any item from dropdown item in array will get sorted with respective item and then from that sorted item user filter filter the data with respective search text.
This looks something like this.
I have no idea to solve this weather should i sort or filter. Any help would be great.

[image: desImage]

> this is how my code looks like

```
const Administrator = (props) => {

  const [menuValues, setMenuValues] = React.useState("");
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

  const [filterText, setFilterText] = useState("");





  const DataReceived = (state) =>
    state.AllUsers.Admin.site_managers.data._embedded;
  const selectedData = useSelector(DataReceived, shallowEqual);
  const selectedDataAgain = selectedData
    ? selectedData.adminUserResourceList
    : null;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    props.getUserLoadSiteManagers(props.accessToken);

    setTableData(selectedDataAgain);
  }, []);

  function handleChange(event) {
    if (event.target.value) {
      setMenuValues(event.target.value);
    } else {
      setMenuValues("all");
    }
  }


  const handleFilterText = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFilterText(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleFilterClick = () => {
    console.log(filterText);
  };

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="lg">

          <div>
            <Select
              value={menuValues}
              onChange={handleChange}
              input={

              }

            >
              <MenuItem value="all">
                <em>All</em>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={"name"}>Name</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={"designation"}>Designation</MenuItem>
              {/* <MenuItem value={"team"}>Team</MenuItem> */}
              <MenuItem value={"userType"}>User</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={"permission"}>Permission</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <TextField

              onChange={handleFilterText}
              value={filterText}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.dense}>
          <ButtonBig onClick={handleFilterClick} title="Apply Filter" />
        </div>
      </Card>

      <Table
        data={TableData}
        isItemSelected
        numSelected={() => numSelected(numSelected)}
        onClick={SelectedId(SelectedId)}
      />


    </Container>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do both at the same time. In the place where you are building the table data, you can put something like this:

```
<Table
    data={{...TableData.filter((item) => filterText ? <here you should filter the item> : true)}
    .sort(item => item[menuValues] > item[menuValues] /*here made the comparation to sort the list*/)}
    isItemSelected
    numSelected={() => numSelected(numSelected)}
    onClick={SelectedId(SelectedId)}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a separate array for displaying your content as so:

`const filteredItems = useMemo(() => tableData.slice(), [tableData])`

note `.slice` here to make a shallow copy instead of referencing the original array.

Once the user clicks on a sort you simply call `.sort` with your criteria and respectively with search text you call `.filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterText.toLowerCase()))`

And finally use this array to display your items at all times.

Comment: Is it the right way to solve the problem i m facing  I mean I am not sure weather i should sort this or not.  Actually from the dropdown user will choose  the field in which they want  to search the respective text field

Comment: If I misunderstood your question and you wish to 'sort' items respectively with the dropdown value and search text (both to account at once) then you can simply store values of `tableData` property names in your dropdown selection and simply filter the items like I had displayed above except switching out the `.name` property with your dynamic property accessor which you save on dropdown click: `item[selectedFilterProp]...`